# Django render_to_string <body><head> tag

Tags: python, html, django

I'm my django app I would like to load a static html page into a main template. This static html page is an email template. My goal is to edit this email in my main template. The email html page don't have a view in url.py. I don't use `include` in main template and I don't want to use iframe. The problem is that I would like to load ALL the html email tag (like

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <body>
```

) but when I do the page's render this tag is deleted (or I don't see them in main template...). This is my code:

**view.py**

```
def my_view(request):
    file_name = "/templates/path/emailtemplate.html"
htmlblock = render_to_string(file_name, {})
return render_to_response('main_template.html', {
        'htmlblock': htmlblock,
    },
    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**main_template.html**

```
    <html>

<head>
  ....
  <head>
    <body>
      <div id="content">
        {{htmlblock}}
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**this is what I would like to have:**

```
<html>

<head>
  ....
  <head>
    <body>
      <div id="content">
        <html>
        <head>
          ....
        </head>

            <body>
              ...
            </body>
        </html>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible without iframe? Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT

My goal is to have the

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <body>
```

tag into

```
 <div id="content">
```

where I load the email template.

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking, you're also missing an end quote in your "view"

Comment: Thanks @Sayse. I have update my description. I hope now is more clear

Answer (score 1):

`My goal is to edit this email in my main template.`

You can read the template into string by

```
with open('/templates/path/emailtemplate.html', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
```

You can use the same as a value to an edit field and it will be visible as usual. This can be used as.

```
return render_to_response('main_template.html', {
        'htmlblock': content,
    }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

You can further use the same in edit field as:

```
<textarea value={{htmlblock}}>
```

Or render the same normally in

```
<div id="content">{{htmlblock}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't know if this works. If I get the 'emailtemplate.html' like a string in the main template I see the code and not the email rendered.

Comment: Ohh, I got confused when you say edit. If you want to render it, there is no mainstream way you can use <html> tag inside a div.